# use hosts file with proxy

Tags: proxy, hosts-file, nsswitch.conf

It is obvious that local **/etc/hosts** file is ignored when using a proxy while browsing.
How can I use hosts file when using a proxy?
I've access to the proxy server. I changed **/etc/hosts** file on the proxy server itself, it did work when I use a browser from the the proxy itself, although it didn't work at all for all the clients connecting through it. It is totally ignored.

from the proxy server (running proxidize.com)

*/etc/nsswitch.conf*

```
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mymachines dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

*/etc/resolv.conf*

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
ip_address www.website.com
```

when opening [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) from a browser from the same proxy box, it is resolving using **/etc/hosts** file, but this hosts file is ignored for all connections using the proxy server

How can I force all proxy users to use the hosts file of the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

In the common Squid proxy for example you can enable/disable the system default and/or select an alternative hosts file with the `hosts_file` option. You will also need to restart Squid to pick up any changes in that hosts file as it is only processed during Squid startup.

See: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/hosts_file/

In other proxy servers things may work differently or similar.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy and a host file are two separate things. A host file has a translation from name to ip, and a proxy is for redirecting a certain traffic flow through another system (for example http)